# How to search with in all objects of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using search(str, array), it is searching only in one field on the array.

My array looks like:

```
array[i].name
array[i].binary
```

Here string is been searched with in name field only.

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of your problem, including an example.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an array of objects. If you want to iterate over the properties of each object in the array, you can use a `for..in` loop:

```
var array = [{property1:'p1',property2:'p2',property3:'p3'},{prop1:'pro1',prop3:'pro3'},{test:{},name:''}];
var str = 'test';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var property in array[i]) {
        if (array[i].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            /* Your search code here */

            /* Search the property name */
            search(str, property);
            /* Search the values of each property */
            search(str, array[i][property]);
        }
    }
}

function search(s, p) {
    console.log(p);
}
```

I edited the code to add [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9M8Kt/) of using `search()` on the values.

Comment: can't we do it without the loop?

Comment: @user3736307 The only way to do it without the loop is to manually call the function on each property of each object.

Comment: default it is searching in first field of the array? or any other logic is there ?

Comment: @Prateek I added an example of how you can use the `search` function on the value of the object properties, instead of their names.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
arr.filter(function(item){ 
   if (item.hasOwnProperty("propName")) { 
        return item["propName"] === 'demo 01'; //or item.propName === 'demo 01'
   } 
   return false;   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Underscore.js library @ http://underscorejs.org ; It has many great utilities for slicing and dicing data from arrays.

In this case, you could use the _.findWhere function. For example:

```
var results = _.findWhere(array, {name: "John"});
```

returns all array[i] items where array[x].name === "John".